# Problem installing WebLogic Server on Mac OS

Tags: macos, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, java-ee-7

When I run the java -jar command **java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls.jar** in a WebLogic/ directory I created for the installation, I receive this error:

```
 akh@akhs-MacBook-Pro ~/WebLogic: java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerSpi: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:672)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1232)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerSpi.getDataHandlerProvider(DataHandlerSpi.java:81)
    at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.getDataHandlerProvider(DaoHelper.java:123)
    at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.parse(DaoHelper.java:170)
    at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.getRootWrapper(DaoHelper.java:398)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getOptionsInfoDao(OptionsParser.java:516)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.parseOptionsDao(OptionsParser.java:189)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.<init>(OptionsParser.java:136)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getInstance(OptionsParser.java:123)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.OUIOptions.<init>(OUIOptions.java:58)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputsImpl.<init>(InputsImpl.java:53)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputsImpl.<clinit>(InputsImpl.java:37)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.helpers.InputHandler.getInputs(InputHandler.java:41)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.processCommandLineArgs(Launcher.java:3135)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:3840)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:3801)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2152)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:659)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:656)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:667)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 27 more
```

I have set up my JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile.  Echo for $JAVA_HOME is: "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home". I have tested and run "java --version" and I get

```
openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

I am running on macOS Mojave version 10.14.5, my JDK is 8 at path /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java.
I don't know why the Java is breaking and the installer is not running.

Comment: WebLogic Server 12.2.1.2 is not supported on OpenJDK and runs only with Oracle JDK 7 or 8.

Comment: thank you, I will download Oracle JDK 8 and use another path

Comment: thank you, I have installed JDK8, but my JAVA_HOME variable in .bash_profile was still the openJDK.  I went in and edit it to '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home' and now the installer is working.

Answer (score 0):

first you must install correct jdk, not openjdk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).